# How to avoid original msg while reply using PHP?

Tags: php, email

Dear all,
        how to avoid original message while reply for incoming mail using php, Am download the mail from mail server, the message content ll be combine with original messages, so its confused, and some of html entities are placed with that content,because of that original messages,
        So how to avoid that original messages using php, anyone can help me...

Thanks in Advance....

Regards,
Vinoth S

Comment: You are replying automatically to incoming messages? How? You must either add the content yourself or using a library, because there is no standard "reply" mechanism in PHP.

Comment: Do you want to remove HTML Entities from your message content?

Comment: @Starx: yes i want to remove html entities from that content and also try to split the original msg

Comment: @Kling: No, but am download that mail from that mail server andsend again through my code, so the download content have that original msg, thats y i want to avoid that original msg... thanks..

Comment: I think a simple strip_tags() can remove all html entities.

Comment: @VinothPHP: Ah... so you are downloading an email which *is* a reply and you want to strip the original message from that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if this is your answer but

```
$message = preg_replace ('/<[^>]*>/', '', $message);
```

OR

```
$message = strip_tags($message);
```

Will remove all the html entities from your message? Try it